# Substitute variables in a String read from a file using Groovy

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

New to groovy as part of upskilling, please help.
I have a text file with content below:

`Name is $vName City is $vCity`

I read this file as follows.

```
def vName="John" 
def vCity="NewYork"
def fData = readFile(file: "c:\data.txt")
print fData
```

I would need to replace the variables vName and vCity with its values and print them.
Is there a way i can get the variables resolved ?

I have executed the script. but it does not work

Comment: Have you tried one of the template engines:
https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-templates/src/test/groovy/groovy/SimpleTemplateEngineTest.groovy#L23

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it could be solved with SimpleTemplateEngine:

```
// declare your file (we'll use a temp file and set example content)
def file = File.createTempFile('template', 'file')
file.text = 'Name is $vName City is $vCity'
// example variables added to binding
vName="John"
vCity="NewYork"
// use simple template engine
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
file.withReader { reader ->
    def template = engine.createTemplate(reader).make(binding.variables)
    assert template.toString() == 'Name is John City is NewYork'
}
```

Comment: The file content can be any of the following , and the content is huge. i just gave an example of 2 variables, 
Eg: 1. Name is $vName City is $vCity
2. age is $vAge, town is $vTown
The Variables in the file though , are defined in my groovy scripts. So essentially i will not be able to assign file.text = 'Name is......" as i will not know the content of the file.

Comment: The file.text part is not an essential part of the answer. It was just used to have a self-contained runnable version of your problem. You said you were reading from a file, so I just created a temporary file with your example contents. Just use a reader for your existing file like I did with the temporary one.